# C++ - align all allocated double arrays to 32bytes

Tags: c++, arrays, alignment, new-operator, avx

I have a quite a large code and I want to optimize some operations by AVX instructions. Based on my tests, improvement should be up to 4x.

However, the code uses plain old arrays (no std::vector) with new operator.

```
double * tmp = new double[size];
```

The problem is, for AVX, I need all double arrays aligned to 32-bytes boundary. The solution is to replace all `new` with `aligned_alloc` (or `_aligned_malloc` in MSVC) and also replace release functions with adequate one. The problem with this is I have to go through all the code and find all `new`, hoping not to forget one and in future everyone must not forget to use aligned alocator.

Is there any other way? I have thought of overload `new` operator only for `double` but I am not sure if this is the correct way and if so, how to do this correctly / safely.

I cannot switch to `std::vector` with own aligned alocator because of some external C-only libs that take array as an input params.

Comment: Just to be extra sure: when you write _"because of some external C-only libs that take array as an input params"_, you mean you cannot give them `vector.data()` because those libs keep the pointer potentially after the vector has invalidated it? or because the libs `delete` the memory themselves? Or some kind of things like that?

Comment: If you can use a static buffer you can use your compiler specific options like `#pragma align`

Comment: @YSC: Obviously, a C library is not going to call `delete`.

Comment: @MSalters ^^ I meant `free()` but I'm so used to `delete` my fingers type it without I noticing :D (I call this reflex a "digital" garbage collector)

Comment: @Martin  Could not you use std::vector with an ad hoc allocator, and pass to your C-only external C libraries  a pointer to the underlying array as returned by vec.data() ?

Comment: @YSC C-library may keep data internally and return them via some "get like function", when they need to be released. Releasing is done on C++ side, but vector may be gone already together with object that allocated him. Or maybe reused, which again invalidate its internal data.

Comment: [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) , [aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Comment: @MSalters but if `new[]` is the solution to the problem, then surely the problem must be the use of `delete[]` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any other way? Yes, `_mm_loadu_*` and `_mm_storeu_*`, where the `u` stands for unaligned.

Comment: This works best if the CPU architecture is at least Haswell (2013) or Zen (2017); on older platforms there might be slight slowdown compared to aligned access.

Comment: I have done some tests and there is no visible difference on my CPU.